# Rolling back a deleted topic leads to an "Oops" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-topics

I just tried to undelete [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html5-canvas/4555/dragging-shapes-on-canvas-a-6-part-tutorial-by-example#t=20160729175901467) on Documentation. What I did:

- From that deleted topic page, followed the link to "View prior to deletion"
- On the topic page, clicked "Create draft rolling back to this revision"

This lead to an "Oops, something bad happened" page. The draft which got created in the tags' dashboard also lead to an "Oops" page.

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a few interesting bugs interacting here:

- Deleted topics usually 404, but obviously shouldn't when there's a draft that undeletes it (you have to be able to see the change after all); this wasn't happening correctly, and instead a draft was being displayed as if it were frozen (as if it were submitted for review, or already reviewed)
- The frozen draft page made an assumption that it was possible to comment on a draft, which isn't true of unsubmitted drafts.  This caused the "Oops"-page you saw.
- Undeleting a topic undeletes at least one example (and possibly more), naturally.  Some old code in the edit pipeline made an assumption that examples being undeleted weren't normally loaded on a topic (which was once true, but is no longer), resulting in an draft that undeletes a topic having multiple copies of the same example.  Collisions in the ids of those examples caused all sorts of fun clientside bugs too.

These have all been fixed in the latest deploy.

Comment: I tested out undeleting a topic discussed in the Docs chat room earlier. Seems to still not work, but maybe I'm doing it wrong. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32897222#32897222 (I'm not actually going to undelete this myself, since it's about a language I don't use.)

Comment: @Frank iiiiinteresting - I see that error in the logs but it looks "impossible".  Digging in.

Comment: @Frank Made some tweaks and found what might have been the issue, try again?